# How to display console.log in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display `console.log` in html?
I tried many things but can't get it.
I want this `out.guild.members.length` to display in html.
Someone can help me?

Thanks!

```
let url = 'MyURL';

fetch(url)
// Send an HTTP request to the API using fetch.
.then(res => res.json())
// Parse the data as JSON.
.then((out) => {
  console.log(out.guild.members.length);
  // Retrieve the member count.
 
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

Comment: What do you mean? Where to display it? If you want to show it on a specific place on your page, put an element there with an ID/class that you can identify it by and then query for the element in JavaScript and set its innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not quite getting your question
but if you want to display `out.guild.members.length` in some div in HTML you can add a div inside your HTML.

HTML:

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=out.guild.members.length;
```